# Erro ao repassar Parâmetros Ajax para função em classe PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html5

É A Primeira vez que tento passar parâmetros do ajax para a minha função que está em uma classe no php, por isso pergunto, por que não está funcionando?
pesquisando no forum vi que poderia colocar

```
data: {
var1 = 'var1',
var2 = 'var2',

},
```

ou repassar pela URL como estou fazendo, mas mesmo dessa forma não obtive sucesso.. o php fala que as variáveis não existem, abaixo o codigo

Ajax - Código foi corrigido - Aqui funciona!

```
  /* Função de Busca - Galeria de Imagens AJAX */
function buscar($tamanho){
    var pasta = $('#pasta').val();  
    // utilizando o split para quebrar o diretorio e receber somente o nome da pasta
    var dirimg = pasta.split("/galeriaimg/");
    var tamanho = $tamanho; 
    var data = {
      tamanho: tamanho,
      diretorio: dirimg[1], 

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',  
         url: '/wpauditoria/painel-admin/include/galeriaimg/galeria.php',      
        //  url: '/wpauditoria/inc/class/Galeriaimg_crud.php?diretorio='+dirimg+'/&tam='+tamanho,  
            data:data,
            success: function(result){ 

               $.each(result, function(key, value){
                    var container = '<div class="col-md-4" id="col-'+key+'">';
                    container +=        '<div class="img-wrap">';
                    container +=            '<img src="/wpauditoria/images/'+tamanho+'/galeriaimg/'+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" class="img-return" alt="galeria" "/>';    
                    container +=            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete" onclick="excluir('+key+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'; 
                    container +=         '</div>';    

                    container +=         '<input type="hidden" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][endereco]" value="/galeriaimg/'+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" />';    
                    container +=         '<input type="text" placeholder="Título" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][titulo]" class="form-control inputgaleria" />';   
                    container +=         '<textarea name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][descricao]" placeholder="Descricao" class="form-control inputgaleria" ></textarea>';   
                    container +=    '</div>';   

                    $('#galeriaimg').append(container);
               });

               /* monstrando os botoes que foram ocultados.*/
               $('.oculto').show();
              $('.group').remove();
         }
    });
}
```

Classe :

```
Class Galeriaimg_crud {

    public function __construct() {
     //
    }

        ///////////////////////////////// FUNÇÃO PARA TRATAR OS ARQUIVOS DO DIRETORIO///////////////////////
    // Função que verifica que verifica se todos os retornos são arquivos e retira os invalidos

    function verifica($param){
        if (!is_dir($param)){
            return $param;
        }
    }

///////////////////////////////// FUNÇÃO PARA OBTER OS ARQUIVOS DO DIRETORIO///////////////////////
        public function arquivos(){

                  $diretorio = $_POST["diretorio"];
                  $tam = $_POST["tamanho"];                    

                    // repassando o caminho para a variavel
                    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wpauditoria/images/$tam/galeriaimg/$diretorio";

                    // escaneando o diretorio através do scandir
                    $files = scandir($dir);                    

                    // realizando um filtro no retorno dos dados do diretorio
                    $result = array_filter($files, 'Galeriaimg_crud::verifica');                             

                    // codificando o retorno através do json_encode  
                    // retorno do conteudo
                    return json_encode($result);
            }
```

Print do Console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para Debugar estou chamando a classe através de um botão da seguinte forma. O Código foi alterado para Get em vez de post mas mesmo assim não funcionou (Atualizei aqui...)

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['cadastrar'])){

  $galeriaimg_crud = new Galeriaimg_crud();

  $result = $galeriaimg_crud->arquivos();
  var_dump($result);

}

?>
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo, é que você está passando os parametros via `GET` mas o método do `ajax` está definido como `POST` isso jamais vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então o objeto em javascript tem erro de s*yntax* deveria ser assim:

```
var data = {
    chave1: 'valor1',
    chave2: 'valor2'
}
```

Para poderes passar este objecto pelo ajax segue este pequeno exemplo

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "MinhaPagina.php",
 data: data, 
 success: function(data) {
      alert('sucesso!');
 },
 error: function(){
     alert('ocorreu um erro!');
 }
});
```

No php poderás capturar assim:

```
echo $_POST['chave1']; // valor1
echo $_POST['chave2']; // valor2
```

Comment: obrigado! fiz dessa forma que vc falou e  acabei descobrindo o problema, na verdade eu estava chamando na url do ajax a classe diretamente sem instanciar o metodo por isso não funcionava,(para teste  eu estava tentando instanciar a função através de um botão... e aí nao funcionava! ). ai criei um arquivo somente para instanciar essa classe e funcionou! mas ai fiquei com uma duvida, quando utilizar ajax sempre terei que criar um arquivo só para instanciar essa classe e chamar o método? ou consigo fazer isso de outra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Coloque isso no inicio da sua funçao arquivos()

```
$diretorio = $_GET["diretorio"];
$tamanho = $_GET["tam"];
```

No lugar que esta isso:

```
$diretorio = $_POST["dirimg"];
$tamanho = $_POST["tam"];
```

No ajax mude o type para get

Comment: @Sergio, eu ja tinha feito isso, mas continuo recebendo erro dizendo que a variavel é invalida

Comment: No console.log(tamanho, dirimg) aparece o que ?

Comment: no preview não aparece nada.. fica vazio, agora se eu ir em header e em query string parameters ai retorna corretamente, mas para teste coloquei um botão, e chamo a classe mas não funciona.. agora se eu colocar `$_POST['pasta']` ai recebo o retorno somente dessa variável.. as demais não. (atualizei a postagem com a tela do console).

Comment: Não tenho experiencia com POO mas acho que por estar dentro de uma classe vc precisa instanciar a classe e chamar o metodo arquivos();
Se vc colocar o codigo da funçao arquivos() de forma estruturada, sem estar em uma classe, teria que funcionar.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068607/ajax-connect-to-php-oop-webservice

Vc vai precisa instanciar sua classe no php.

    $galeria = new Galeriaimg_crud();
    echo $galeria ->arquivos();

Comment: Blz .. realmente deveria funcionar .. mas e aí q recebo o erro de variável.qdo eu chamo a classe e o método através de  botão  foi a forma q encontrei de debugar, pq o console não tá exibindo nada nenhum erro

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64465/discussion-between-serginho-and-diego-lela).

Answer (score 0):

Problema Resolvido! Obrigado a todos os envolvidos! 
Com a ajuda de vocês consegui identificar aonde estava meu erro...

para testar eu estava instanciando a classe em um botão por isso que não conseguia receber o retorno da variável o php falava que ela não existia.

Bom para resolver, mudei a url do Ajax, chamando um arquivo que criei de nome galeria.php, nele instanciei a classe junto com o meto e com o retorno, o problema foi resolvido. Atualizei o Código na primeira postagem para ele ficar correto no caso de alguém precisar no futuro

galeria.php

```
<?php


      // instanciando a Classe
      $galeriaimg_crud = new Galeriaimg_crud();
      // recebendo o retorno do metodo Arquivos

      $result = $galeriaimg_crud->arquivos();

      // exibindo o retorno
      echo $result;

 ?>
```